# How to edit a Android library .class file

Tags: android, edit, android-library

I am trying to edit [this](https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid) library. The `DragDropGrid.class` to be specific, but I cant. The licence for the code is this:

```
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
 * a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
 * "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
 * without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
 * distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
 * permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
 * the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
 * OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
 * WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
```

So I should be able to edit it. The problem is that nothing happens when I try to. Is there a solution for this odd problem? I tried to google to find a solution, but I got results that told me not to edit the `R` file.

Comment: You should edit the DragDropGrid.java, not *.class

Comment: Thanks, I got to the `*.class` file using the eclipse Ctrl+click functionality, so I was flabbergasted when nothing that I tried worked. @Egor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit the DragDropGrid.java, not *.class - Commented by Egor.